# ERROR 1006 (HY000) Can't create database (errno: 13) MySQL 5.6.12

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I am facing problem creating the database and it results in following error.

```
mysql> show grants for 'admin'@'%';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admin@%                                                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*4ACFE3202A5FF5CF467898FC58AAB1D615029441' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create database abc;
ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'abc' (errno: 13)
```

Here is my users table.

```
mysql> select host, user from mysql.user;
+-------------+-------+
| host        | user  |
+-------------+-------+
| %           | admin |
| 127.0.0.1   | root  |
| ::1         | root  |
| IVM-MMC-DGW | root  |
| localhost   | admin |
| localhost   | root  |
+-------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show grants;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for admin@localhost                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*4ACFE3202A5FF5CF467898FC58AAB1D615029441' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can create and remove table in the existing database.

The data directory already has mysql:mysql privileges and also the logged in user has privilege to create the new database.

What configuration is missing here ?

Comment: show your user table. I meant just the relevant part of it. Select host, user from mysql.user

Comment: check also the permission of temp data direcotry (my.cnf).

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: Try only `show grants;` , maybe you have the privileges for `admin@localhost` which mayb differ.

Comment: The /var/lib/mysql do exists in OS

Comment: This issue is still not fixed. Can some one please help to me to overcome this problem.

Comment: have you try to add --host=127.0.0.1 when connecting to MySQL

Answer (score 34):

There may be a permissions issue with the MySQL data directory. You could try setting the permissions as follows (adjust the path to your data directory)

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

Comment: The data directory already has a permission of mysql:mysql. It is still giving error while creating the database

Comment: For MAMP the databases directory is `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql56`

Comment: @Finesse for MAMP PRO

Answer (score 19):

This happens probably due to permission denied by MySQL. Though you set the `datadir=/drbd0/mysql/data`, but by default MySql `set socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`, so you should have the privileges to that directory.

```
less /etc/group
```

and then

```
less /etc/passwd
```

find mysql user and group name, by default, it's mysql user in mysql group.

change to mysql dir, probably `/var/lib/mysql` and then type `cd ..` to go up one directory.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql ./mysql/
```

Replace `mysql:mysql` with something different if you group and user privileges are called differenty

Comment: chown -R mysql:mysql ./mysql/ worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It might be problem with space.
Follow this

1. Check .err logs at /var/lib/mysql
2. if the log says something like 
   "[ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No space left on device"
3. Check /var size by df -hk /var
4. if used is 100% , then u have to find the files which is geting filled.
5. find large file in /var by 
   find /var/ -type f -size +100000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
6. see which file you can delete and then restart the mysql process by
7. /etc/init.d/mysql restart

let me know if that worked :)

Comment: It was `/etc/init.d/mysqld` in my case

Answer (score 10):

For Mac OS use this command

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql*
```

User `mysql` should have write access to mysql data directory.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks .

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: Could you explain why you did this?

Comment: It means, that owner of mysql folder should be mysql

Comment: saved me some trouble. accidentally ran 'chown -R apache /'. As you can imagine a lot broke when i did this :P sql was the last thing i needed to fix.  this worked for me

Comment: saved me a headache! :'  )

Answer (score 3):

1. Check your mysql data directory permissions.
   The data directory is configured in '/etc/my.conf' by default.
   Or use `mysqladmin -uroot -p variables | grep datadir` to find the directory.
   It may be `/var/lib/mysql/` by default, and makesure the owner user and group 
   is mysql. `chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data`
2. If it has not been solved by step 1. It may be because of `SELinux` in your way, try to [turn off it](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/turn-off-selinux.html).

   - Test if SELinux is running. `selinuxenabled && echo enabled || echo disabled`
   - Turning off SELinux temporarily. `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce`
   - Completely turning off SELinux. Change config `SELINUX=disabled`, and reboot.

   In different os, the configuration directory of  `SELinux` may be different.

Answer (score 2):

if you move the mysql folder and restart mysql, it works

Comment: This can be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In /etc/mysql/my.cnf, set datadir = /home/mysql_data, which 
is the location where the database files actually are on yourmachine

Comment: I have data_dir set as datadir=/drbd0/mysql/data in /etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

Turn off SELinux especially if you're on CentOS.

Check [Turning off or disabling SELinux](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/turn-off-selinux.html).

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, in my case I changed the default directory on my.cf and the selinux has blocking it.

**To test:**

```
setenforce 0
```

**To fix (CentOS)**

Add context and make it permanent

```
semanage fcontext -a -s system_u -t mysqld_db_t "/var/data/mysql(/.*)?" restorecon -Rv /var/data/mysql
```

source: https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2016/01/14/changing-mysql-data-directory-centos-7/

Answer (score 0):

Running WAMP and i had same issue, opted for the traditional stop and start all services and that did it for me. I was able to create the database after that, really don't know why i wasn't able to create it at first as i had no issue with space or permission. Well i hope this helps the WAMP users

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was a problem with owner of MySQL data directory, as suggested by the others. However the setup on my server was quite uncommon, using different directories, so here is more detailed solution:

1. Find MySQL data directory

`grep 'datadir' $(find /etc -iname my.cnf 2>/dev/null) | awk '{print $3}'`

If MySQL configuration is in correct place, it returns e.g. `/var/lib/mysql`

If it doesn't return any result, try to search in the whole filesystem using

`grep 'datadir' $(find / -iname my.cnf 2>/dev/null) | awk '{print $3}'` (this may take a long time)

Break down:

`find /etc -iname my.cnf 2>/dev/null` finds a file named my.cnf in `/etc` ignoring errors

`grep 'datadir' /etc/mysql/my.cnf` finds datadir in the file found in the previous step

`awk '{print $3}'` prints the third column from the standard input

2. Fix the ownership

`sudo chown -R mysql:mysql MYSQLDIR` replacing `MYSQLDIR` with the path to the directory returned in step 1

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently. Database was not getting created. It was throwing error. Later on I found that **disk is 100% full due to which this was happening**. Permissions were all ok.