# MySQL Workbench error when adding a connection

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I'm new to mac and mySQL. I installed mySQL 5.6.14 and mySQLWorkbench 1.6. I turned on mySQL in system preferences.

Then I went into workbench, clicked to add a new connection and filled in the details: host is localhost; username is root; password is empty/nothing. Tested the connection and its all good.

Clicked OK and got this error: Exception caught while processing action from home screen: error calling Python module function WbAdmin.autoDetectLocalInstance.

I also can not access mySQL from the terminal.

I've googled and can't find anything. Has anyone got any ideas of what could be wrong something I could try to fix it.

Comment: Are you running Workbench from within your Applications folder? I had problems with other apps that were solved by moving them to Applications and running it again.

Comment: Yes, it's in the the applications folder. I can actually access mySQL from the terminal but get an error: ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database.

Comment: Check this out: [ERROR 1006 (HY000) Can't create database (errno: 13) MySQL 5.6.12](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22039088/2752041)

Comment: I managed to get it to work. I don't know what the problem was. I uninstalled and reinstalled with mysql 5.6.14 64bit and 5.6.17 (latest version) 32 bit with no avail. And then downloaded and installed the mysql 5.6.17 64bit and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've had de same problem. For me the solution:

Check that you have the file /etc/my.cnf
if you don't have  sudo cp my-default.cnf  on the terminal

Try to put password Virlli$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'password'

Restart Mysql and Workbench

for Mysql :sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop

Answer (score 1):

If you are a mac your default password is root . Same as the username.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. I solved this issue by getting settings section from main window and then connecting from appeared connection from the main window.