# Error Code: 1006. Can't create database 'mmmm' (errno: 2)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

When am trying to create a database on server it shows an error

> Error Code: 1006. Can't create database 'mmmm' (errno: 2)

How can I solve this error?
The server is mysql.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719748/error-1006-hy000-cant-create-database-errno-13-mysql-5-6-12

Comment: am already tried all those steps. but not working

Comment: Do you have permissions to create command?

Answer (score 0):

Likely you do not have permission to create a database.